# How to list and count the different types of node and edge entities in the graph data using SPARQL query?

Tags: graph, rdf, sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm looking to provide some summary stats for a data set and I want to list the different types of edge entities and node(vertex) entities in the graph.

For example:

-> In Twitter Social network graph of users and following relationship (Homogeneous graph), there is only one type of vertex entity (user), but in heterogeneous graphs such as ConceptNet data, it will have multiple values.

-> The edge entities can be computed by just counting the different number of predicates I believe using the query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (?p AS ?DistinctEdges)  { ?s ?p ?o }
```

But I am not sure how to do so for vertices. The vertex type can be from a subject or object field of the triple and the object in turn can be either a value(literal) or another resource itself.

Please excuse me if I have gone wrong with the vocabulary anywhere. I have just started working on building a semantic web application.

Comment: "The vertex type can be from a subject or object field of the triple and the object in turn can be either a value(literal) or another resource itself."  Usually type is indicated by `rdf:type`.  The object should a resource (i.e., not a literal).  Then you just do `select distinct ?type { [] rdf:type ?type }` à la [the default DBpedia SPARQL endpoint query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about `rdf:type` rather node types i.e. URIs, Blank Nodes and Literals

Comment: @RobV That could be,  I don't think it's really clear.  I was basing my comment on this bit: "In Twitter Social network graph of users and following relationship (Homogeneous graph), there is only one type of vertex entity (user)". But, given your comment, it could be that "The vertex type can be from a subject or object field of the triple and the object in turn can be either a value(literal) or another resource itself" is meant to identify all the nodes in the graph (which would include literals, too). If that's the case, I think your answer works, if you remove the filter (and fix bnodes).

Comment: Thanks to both the comments and answer. It is more clear now. To clarify, I wanted to extract the edge and node entities in a graph. Edge entities are straightforward. For node entities, I'll be needing the ones that are a resource or blank node(not sure?). Example: If there is a network consisting of papers(nodes), authors(nodes), conferences(nodes), iswrittenby(edge), ispublishedin(edge), presentsin(edge) and so on... my query would have to return for node type : papers authors conferences and for edge type: iswrittenby, ispublishedin , presentsin etc

Comment: I also have a follow up question on the same topic : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197081/how-to-generate-all-triples-that-fit-a-particular-node-type-or-and-edge-type-usi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UNION` clause to combine two patterns in conjunction with a `FILTER` clause using the `IsLiteral()` function to omit literals e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?vertex
WHERE
{
  { 
    ?vertex ?p [] 
  }
  UNION
  { 
    [] ?p ?vertex 
    FILTER(!IsLiteral(?vertex))
  }
}
```

The `[]` is an anonymous variable because you don't care about the some of the positions on either side of the `UNION` so by giving them an anonymous variable we match any value but don't carry those values out in the query.

The `FILTER` clause in the RHS of the union is used to filter out objects which are literals.  It is not necessary to have this in the LHS because RDF forbids literal subjects so any `?vertex` value from the LHS must be a resource i.e. a URI/blank node

Comment: Yes, I too am getting a syntax error for this query.