# How to generate all triples that fit a particular node type or/and edge type using SPARQL query?

Tags: graph, rdf, sparql, jena, fuseki

It is a follow up question to :

[How to list and count the different types of node and edge entities in the graph data using SPARQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187351/how-to-list-and-count-the-different-types-of-node-and-edge-entities-in-the-graph?noredirect=1#comment37346822_24187351)

So assuming I have the different node entities and edge entities of a given graph, how do I go about listing all triples, given a node-edge-node pattern? And how do I generate ALL node-edge-node patterns given the node and edge entities?

Example: If there is a network consisting of papers(nodes), authors(nodes), conferences(nodes), iswrittenby(edge), ispublishedin(edge), presentsin(edge) and so on , I'd have node entity type : papers authors conferences and for edge entity type: iswrittenby, ispublishedin , presentsin etc

What I'm looking to do now is generate patterns like:

1) paper(node)-iswrittenby(edge)-author(node)
2) paper(node)-iscitedby(edge)-paper(node)
and so on... 
and then generate all triples from the dataset which satisfy these patterns.

Comment: Did RobV's answer to "How to list and count the different types of node and edge entities in the graph data using SPARQL query?" work for you, since this is a followup?  If it is, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437). I mention this because you've got six questions, none of which have accepted answers…

Comment: No...the query isn't working for me yet. I had posted this follow up question assuming I get the previous query working. However, point taken about accepting the answer. it did help me get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may need to clarify that other question then, because as it's written, it seems like RobV's answer is pretty much what the question is asking for.

Comment: He made an edit fixing the error. It works now... no issues. Thanks!

Comment: Great; Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
construct {   
  ?paper :isWrittenBy ?author .
  ?paper :isCitedBy ?paper2
}
where {
  ?paper :isWrittenBy ?author .
  ?paper :isCitedBy ?paper2
}
```

The [spec section on construct queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct) might be a helpful reference.

Comment: This could actually be simplified as `construct where { ?paper :isWrittenBy ?author ; :isCitedBy ?paper2 }`, I think.  Showing the more general form to a new user is important, though.